# How to position an <input> in the center of the <div>

Tags: html, css, alignment

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="check">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="descr"> ... </div>
    <div class="details"> ... </div>
</div>
```

How do I align the checkbox in the middle of the `div.check`, both horizontally and vertically? (the height of the `".item"` div is dynamic)

Comment: `display: table-cell;` is the only option here

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Fmj/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an edit of [Kilian Stinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426252/1050262) code that does not require CSS3 support.
Instead of `translate` I use `em's`:

HTML:

```
<div class="check">
      <input class="center" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.check {
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -.5em;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yzhnf/4/

Answer (score 3):

Try to translate it with css3

HTML

```
<input class="center" type="checkbox">
```

CSS

```
.check {
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzhnf/2/) with a working example.

At first, the element is positioned 50% from the left and 50% from the top. Then it's set back 50% of its own width and height.

For browser support get more information on [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Answer (score 0):

```
position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top..bottom etc
```

if that doesnt work

```
position:absolute; left:50%; right:50%;
```

Comment: You can do `margin:0 auto` or `margin:auto;` instead of naming all of them individually.

Comment: By setting `position: absolute` and `50%` it centers only the top left corner